# blood in cooked chicken

Tags: chicken

I roasted a chicken at 180 using the fan for 1 1/2 hours, when I got it out of the oven, I pierced it and the juices were clear, I ate some slices of the breast, and the first ones looked fine, but a later one had blood or what looked like blood in it, will I be ok or do I need a doctor?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I presume you mean 180°C (355°F)?

Answer (score 2):

More than likely you'll be fine as long as you don't start to feel ill. The recommended cooking temperature for meats is based on the temp required to kill the yucky things in the meat.

Sometimes chicken (especially near the bone) cooks a dark red color, nothing dangerous about it.

Comment: +1 for 'you'll be fine as long as you're not' :)